# TS SyntaxError: Duplicate arguments - same code, different results

Tags: javascript, typescript, syntax, syntax-error, jsfiddle

I am exploring TypeScript lately.

The following code works fine when I run it at `typescriptlang.org`. However, when I execute the same code in `jsfiddle` with TS enabled it will throw the following error:

> "SyntaxError: duplicate argument names not allowed in this context"

## Code used

```js
class Position {
  public constructor(public readonly y: number, public readonly x: number) {}

  public yx(): string {
    return this.y.toString() + this.x.toString();
  }
}

const pos = new Position(1, 5);
console.log(pos);
```

Also, I wonder if I can write the following:

```
public yx(): string {
    return `${this.y}${this.x}`;
}
```

Because `jsfiddle` threw another error at me: `Missing } in Template String.` So I changed it to `this.x.toString()` as in the code above.

## Question

I don't understand why I get these errors. I have two different properties and I thought that the template string should be working too.

Am I missing something or could this be a bug?

## Examples

[working example at typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKD2ECWAXJ8B20DeBYAUNNAA4CuARiEsNMJhCgE6nAryMAUZl10jApmAAmmEAE9oYgFzQMpALbl+jADQkKVGgOGiJADxlzFygJQ4AvgSJX1PGmL0cTMhoyQYA5jhsBIASlJGLBQACyQIADoxCLYAZSZ3DydoAGpoUPCIvRj4eLdPJwBuG0t8UoI6DAYSRGgAXll+AHc4RFR0DA4ARjUAVhNi-EqIeBB+CJB4JOJEAaA)
[not working example at jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjp4eqLu/)

Comment: [This thread](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/1079) suggests to me that JSFiddle isn't the best environment to be running TypeScript code.

Comment: Your snippet is totally correct, probably jsfiddle has an old version of Typescript (< 2.0)

Comment: Well, thank you guys for the feedback. I thought that the version might be more current. Too bad, you cannot see the version of TS in the jsfiddle application itself. The threads that date back to like 2017 are not necessarily the newest source of information whatsoever. But in this case, it might hold true after all. I guess you are right here. That would indeed be a plausible explanation. I might try another web app then.

Comment: @F.Müller [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-dan-jhlik?file=/src/index.ts) is nice.

Comment: @spender Thanks. Looks great. :)